# How to compile the paraview source code to the Qt project (.pro)?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, vtk, paraview

I have just compiled the source code to the VS solution (.sln), is there a way to compile it to the Qt project. It seems greater convenience to me to handle the UI design in this way. My current working environments are Paraview version 5.4.1, Visual Studio 2015 and Qt Creator 4.4.1.

Comment: Use CMake instead of QMake.

Comment: Select the `qmake` generator in CMake GUI (I suppose that's the interface to CMake you're using since you mentioned Visual Studio - meaning you're on Windows) and open the resulting `.pro` in Qt Creator. Or, import the CMake project directly - Qt Creator is able to do that.

Comment: I did not find the qmake generator in the CMake GUI，version3.9.4. But the second method works for me, many thanks to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I do it.

- download paraview source, create a build directory
- run a Visual Studio Command (VS2013 X64 Native Tools Command)
- within the command, configure paraview using CMake
- Open QtCreator, Open the CMakeLists.txt
- Select the correct build you just configured and click on configure project
- Build -> Build All

However, IMHO, using QtCreator is unnecessary. You can use designer to handle UI changes, SublimeText to edit code and Ninja to build from within the Visual Studio Command. Much more efficient.

Comment: yes, I also did this, then generate a makefile. But what to do next, I am a novice, Thank you！

Comment: OK. Thank you very much.